# How to log Kernel Panic?

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, log

I got Ubuntu 18.04 running on old kernel 4.4 and 4.9, maybe some in between or after would work as well, but these work for me and I can boot into them.

Edit: 4.13 works as well.

Issue I have is that past 4.14 no kernel work and each one of them gives kernel panic on boot.

I tried looking into logs to find what causes panic but there was no logs(makes sense, because journal isn't started at time.).

I tried doing kernel panic force that I found on Wiki but non successfully. 
Can someone give me step by step guide on how to do it, so that I can figure out why I have those panics. Or give suggestions on how to figure why is all this happening.

I can't read almost anything from console output during boot/panic because resolution is very small ,so very little text stays on screen for me to read.
Exit code is 0x00000009.

If it means, I tried putting boot usb Arch and I also had kernel panic.

Edit 2 26.03.2019: ls -la output

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 мар 26 01:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 мар 26 00:40 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1472334 нов 24  2017 abi-4.13.16-041316-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1402742 мар 23 14:44 abi-4.9.165-0409165-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   211697 нов 24  2017 config-4.13.16-041316-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   201339 мар 23 14:44 config-4.9.165-0409165-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   224094 мар 23 21:59 config-5.0.4-050004-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 мар 26 01:27 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 56597111 мар 26 01:03 initrd.img-4.13.16-041316-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 39849072 мар 26 01:03 initrd.img-4.9.165-0409165-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 64550786 мар 26 01:28 initrd.img-5.0.4-050004-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 51698578 мар 24 21:55 initrd.img-5.0.4-050004-generic-kdump
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 јан 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 јан 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 јан 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  3871207 нов 24  2017 System.map-4.13.16-041316-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3664778 мар 23 14:44 System.map-4.9.165-0409165-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4363509 мар 23 21:59 System.map-5.0.4-050004-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7812880 нов 24  2017 vmlinuz-4.13.16-041316-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  7497504 мар 23 14:44 vmlinuz-4.9.165-0409165-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8681344 мар 23 21:59 vmlinuz-5.0.4-050004-generic-kdump
```

Solution:
I am using HP motherboard. Bios was outdated 1.04, so I updated Bios to 1.60 and now it works. Able to boot even in 5.04 kernel. Gonna test others as well, which I assume will work as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91556/discussion-on-question-by-alek95-how-to-log-kernel-panic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments and chat...

After trying a number of things that didn't fix the problem, we updated the BIOS from 1.04 to 1.60, and kernel 5.0.4 now boots fine!

Comment: Another +1 for another good job! Newer kernels should do sanity checks and know they break with older BIOS. Then an appropriate error message can be displayed instead of "Kernel Panic"